# String/char arrays inside struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a struct that has multiple string arrays inside of it. For my purposes I wanted to use std::string arrays but char * arrays would also work if they can get the job done. Either way I can't figure out how to initialize things. This is what I have:

initialize.h

```
#include <string>

struct myStruct
{
    std::string x[22];
    std::string y[8];
};

extern myStruct data[22];
```

myform.cpp

```
#include <initialize.h>
#include <string>

myStruct data[22];

data[0].x = {"a", "b", "c", "d", ...};
```

I am getting errors that look like this:

Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '{' 
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

I have tried various permutations with char * arrays or std::string * arrays instead but to no avail, I am quite stuck. Did I forget something fundamental?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are declaring 660 distinct strings. Is that your intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the { } array initialization syntax to assign values to arrays. It can only be used when initializing the array right after definition:

```
int a[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };
```

but not

```
int a[3];
a = { 3, 4, 5 }; //error
```

you will not get around a loop or a manual initialization of every member. But I think the new C++0x standard improves upon this and makes this (and even more initializer syntax) possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
myStruct data[22];
```

With the above statement, you have already created **22** objects of type `myStruct` and each object having it's own `x,y` string arrays whose size is **22,8** respectively.

You can only initialize each member of an array directly only while **declaration** and not during **assignment** operation. So, you can try -

```
data[0].x[0] = "a";
data[0].x[1] = "b";

// ....
```

What the error you are doing is something similar to -

```
int a[5] ;
a = { 1,2,3,4,5 } ; // Error.

int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 } ; // Correct.
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
  {"a", "b", "c", "d", ...};
```

syntax is only allowed when defining a variable, so you could do

```
  std::string data[4] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};  // syntax allowed for definition
```

but the line

```
  data[0].x = {"a", "b", "c", "d", ...}; // not definition
```

is not a definition (data[0].x isn't a new variable). Moreover, since this is not a definition, you can't actually place this code outside of a function.

Somewhere in code you're going to have to manually assign each variable (as @Mahesh's answer suggests)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to initialize non static array members in C++. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you make these `char *` instead of strings, you could get away with a static initializer. It's going to be long and ugly though.

```
struct myStruct
{
    char * x[22];
    char * y[8];
};

extern myStruct data[22];

myStruct data[22] = {
    { // data[0]
        { "a", "b", "c", ... "v" }, // data[0].x
        { "0", "1", ... "7" } // data[0].y
    },
    { // data[1]
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The other comments are correct but I believe there is one other thing you can do.  You can initialize the structure when you declare it in your header:

```
struct myStr
{
  string x[22];
  string y[8];
} data[22] = { {...}, {...}, ... };
```

This too will be long and ugly but might address your question.  As others have said, you can't extern this and assign to it after instantiation.